# C set executable permissions through Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, setuid

I am using a Makefile to compile my C program and want to make the executable setuid. How can I set the permissions using the Makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you would from the command line (`chmod u+s .....`) - just have it be the line after you've created the executable

note too that that you could, in addition, do a `sudo chown root:root .....`

Answer (score 1):

If your environment has `install` utility you can do it like:

```
install: program
    install -m 4755 -o root program /usr/local/bin

.PHONY: install
```